# Terminate running perl script started with CGI

Tags: perl, websocket, cgi, infinite-loop

I am creating a Perl script that creates a `Net::WebSocket::Server` on port 3000. Now I had the (not so brilliant) idea to start the script in the browser via CGI, so it runs in the background and can't be stopped. However, I have to restart the script whenever I modify it.

Is it possible to stop a CGI script in an endless loop, except by restarting the computer?

Comment: I don't see why you think it matters that it was started from a CGI script. Stop the program that way you always do (sending it a signal?)

Comment: You want to stop it with an external process? For example you want to have an app that watches on the timestamp of the script and when it changes you want it to stop the script execution and run it again?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what operating system you are on, so we cannot give you specific advice on how to find and kill the process. But you can always restart the web server application. CGI scripts are children of the server process (probably an Apache) that starts them. If you simply restart the Apache server, they should all be terminated.

Please don't put code that is supposed to run persistently in your cgi-bin directory. That's a bad idea, as you discovered.

Comment: Everything points to a program launched from the CGI script, so the apache process is not the parent as you claim, but `init` (after its previous parent, the CGI script, existed). Restarting apache won't help.

Comment: @ikegami I took a quick look at [the source of Net::WebSocket::Server](https://metacpan.org/source/TOPAZ/Net-WebSocket-Server-0.003004/lib/Net/WebSocket/Server.pm) and I think that in fact the CGI script that apache started keeps running in an endless loop. What points you to the conclusion that it's a program launched from that script?

Comment: CGI scripts can't run forever, and the OP says it runs in the background.

Comment: @ikegami hmm. True, apache would kill it after 5 minutes or something. You're right.